# Import tiles OpenStreetMap QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, layers, tiles, google

I have a map in QGIS that is supposed to have multiple layers, a custom made map, and a google street/openstreetmap layer.

The layers somehow don't work, and so I decided to make a new connection. I followed the instructions, used the correct urls for both Google street as OpenStreetMap, but there was nothing to see. I adapted the CRS of both these files with the correct ones (it matched the CRS of the visible layers), but still nothing to see even if I de-zoom.

Can someone give me a hint of what the problem could be?

Here a a few screenshots:

Here can you check the url I am using:
[image]

Here the url and CRS:
[image]

The references I have, even after selecting the layer. Zooming Dezooming is the same.

[image]

I just noticed that somehow now there are errors appearing.
I get those two errors:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Press `F12` to open the Development Tools and check if there are any errors. Maybe you have to skip SSL host / certificate verification: set `GDAL_HTTP_UNSAFESSL` environment variable to YES.

Comment: I'd suggest adding screenshots of your layers panel, your connection setups, and your CRS details. At the moment there is not really enough information to go on.

Comment: @christoph F12 doesn't show any errors.

Comment: @TomBrennan I added a few screenshots to my question

Comment: @cobdmg Google XYZ (TMS) uses CRS EPSG:3857 and not EPSG:31370.

Comment: I think the "I adapted the CRS of both these files with the correct ones" steep is the faulty one As QGIS do on the fly reprojection you shouldn't have to adjust any of the CRS (unless a CRS layer are not defined never "adjust" it)

Comment: @J.R Initially I didn't pay much attention to the CRS, but as I got no resutls, I just tried changing the CRS

Comment: @christoph I thought I needed to change CRS. But even if I select the EPSG:3857, there is nothing to see

Comment: It possible install the QuickMapService plugin and add your google and OSM from it, it usually work well and you have nothing to configure so the risk of error is lower...

Answer (score 0):

The problem came from my VPN who blocked everything. Changing to another network solved the problem.